# How to delete all variables after finishing the execution in Python GUI?

Tags: python, pyqt5

My GUI program which is written by PyQt5, has 4 tabs which I run the other tab after finishing the current tab. For example execute Tab1 and after saving the results i go to second tab and run that tab. My question is that after finishing the execution of the current tab, how can i delete all variables which i have created during the execution of this tab. I mean deleting variables from the RAM.
Does using `gc.collect` at the end of that tab remove the variables?
Any answer would be very helpful for me.

Comment: `del` variables

Comment: I am curious about the use case for explicitly deleting variables.  Once variables go out of scope, Python should take care of all that.  Is it a security thing, or a performance expectation, or what?

Comment: As long as these aren't global variables and they're not "self" attributes, they should get garbage collected when they go out of scope, right?

Comment: Note that `del` does *not* delete/destroy/remove the object from memory: it deletes the *reference*. As long as there is *any* other reference to the same object, it will not be garbage collected. Also, as long as the python interpreter is running and further processing doesn't reclaim the memory addresses used by the "deleted" resources, they could still be available at some level (even if only at low level using debugging tools). The only safe way to destroy the *content* of memory used by a program is by quitting it - theoretically.

Comment: @RufusVS it is about performance. Since i have several tabs in GUI, I dont want to store variables in RAM because of performance issues. I need to delete all variables which are created on that tab to free RAM. Is there any efficient way?

Comment: @bfris Some of them are local, but i have many variables which are "self". Is there any efficient way to destroy / delete all variables of that tab after finishing the execution of it? After finishing Tab1, I should execute Tab2 and i dont want Tab1 variables to waste the RAM

Comment: @musicamante yes it is true. using ```del``` is not the solution for me. I want to completely remove them from RAM as the Tab1 finishes

Comment: @Orca then the only way is to ensure that your code is properly written (without "loose references") and all variables are stored in the objects that are part of that tab: if the tab contents are stored using a class instance, then removing that instance should be quite enough. Note that for QTabWidget this means that you not only remove the tab content, but also call `deleteLater()`.

Comment: Set the `Qt.WA_DeleteOnClose` [widget-attribute](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#setAttribute), and explicitly call `close()` when the tab is no longer needed. Qt will automatically recursively delete all the child widgets as well, so make sure they form a self-contained hierarchy with the tab as the root. You must also make sure there are no hidden references lurking elsewhere in your code. One common way for this to happen is via signal-slot connections that form a closure (e.g. when using `lambda` with `self`).

Answer (score 0):

You can try `del` statement

> Deletion of a name removes the binding of that name from the local or
> global namespace, depending on whether the name occurs in a global
> statement in the same code block. If the name is unbound, a NameError
> exception will be raised.

```
a = 1
b = 2
print(a)
print(b)
del a, b
print(b)


# NameError: name 'b' is not defined
```

Comment: yes i am familiar with del but since there are too many variables, it is not easy to delete them one by one. I dont't think del can help me in this situation

Comment: Can you encapsulate your variables in an object, and delete the object?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's a way to delete all of them built-in so I would add them to a var list when declaring them and delete all of them at once when ready.

```
    varlist = []
    
    myvar1 = 'string'
    varlist.append(myvar1)

    myvar2 = 123
    varlist.append(myvar2)

    for var in varlist:
        del var
```

Comment: Of course this is one of the solutions but it is not efficient in my case since there are so many variables and there about 1000 line code. i cant not start from beginning to append  them